# How can I see if legal anime subs are available in a certain language for streaming?

Tags: resources, crunchyroll

I'd like to watch anime (legally) with French subtitles (while not in a French-speaking region), since I'm trying to improve my French. How can I easily see anime that has French subtitles available legally? Some sites (namely Crunchyroll) have non-English subtitles, but it's impossible to see whether or not a specific series has those non-English subtitles available until I get to the episode page (or possibly a page for the series - I'm not completely sure).

I would like to be able to have sort of list to see whether or not I can watch anime X in language Y (or possibly at least have some way to know this without looking at specific entries for each series). How can this be done? With some languages such as English or Chinese it's generally pretty simple, but with others it doesn't seem as clear.

Comment: Related: http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2013/10/02/crunchyroll-launches-streaming-service-in-france

Comment: @MiharuDante: Thanks. Weirdly enough though (as someone accessing the site from the US) the crunchyroll.fr site is essentially giving me everything in English....

Comment: Each video has a list of available subtitle languages on the sidebar (under the episode name and summary), you just need to click the language of your choice to change the subs to that language. If you're registered you canet the default language under your user setting ("Video Settings").

Comment: If you wish to watch anime subbed in French, [Wakanim](http://www.wakanim.tv/) is a service not unlike Crunchyroll for streaming/simulcast anime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. On Crunchyroll there is a workaround to this.

---

### Step 1

Head over to the footer or bottom of the website. It should look something like this >

[image]

### Step 2

From the footer, head over to languages in the footer, then head over to the highlighted text which says 'French'

[image]

### Step 3

After this the page should reload and the animes should now be playing with French subtitles.

Note: Not sure if it will work, but it did work for me. Have a look in the picture below. Try it on Golden Time Episode 24.

### [image]

Comment: This just changes the site language to French. The videos are subbed in English.

Comment: @Krazer- I think they are too actually, but it did work for me. Could you try to reproduce what I did in my steps to see if it works for you. I kind of edited my answer, not sure if it will work though.

Comment: I see the problem, you need to select the subtitle language from the sidebar ("sous-titres"), so it correctly adds the ssid query string for the language (it defaults to English), e.g., http://www.crunchyroll.com/chaika-the-coffin-princess-/episode-4-the-dragoons-wish-653317?ssid=111083

Comment: If you're registered you can save your default language (for video subs) in your preferences.

Comment: Yep, this seems to work - the videos sort to only the ones with subs in the appropriate language. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Follow the above instructions, then [view the lineup](http://www.crunchyroll.com/lineup). When your language is set to French, what you can see in the lineup are the videos available in your region with French subtitles. If you are at the lineup page and flip between different languages at the bottom of the page, you should see different numbers of show for each language ... for myself, in the US, I see:

Continuing Titles: English, 10; Spanish 6; Portuguese, same 6; French 4.

New Titles: English 37; Spanish, Portuguese & French, 33.

But if I accessed the site from Canada, the numbers in the French section would increase, since a few French Language licenses are not available in English in North America but are available in French in Canada.

Also, (1) this is just an automatic filter, so its only as good as the setting of the database, and mistakes are always possible in setting that database up and (2) for devices (Android, iOS, etc.) or for some titles where Crunchyroll has hardsubs (normally in English) you need to also change your language preferences to get the right result.